# Trying to overwrite the service endpoints of the subscribed services for an application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to use existing service definitions in a new application but relocating the service endpoints to a different server. Is this possible or do I have to create new service versions of each service and then define the new endpoint in this version definition?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't these applications subscribed to APIs?

Comment: My idea is to have several applications which are subscribed to some APIs (the same APIs) but the endpoints of the API should be different and my question is: Is this possible only by defining different APIs (different versions) or is there an easier way. I want to have the APIs deployed in several environments but using only one WSO2 APIM.

Comment: Ideally, you need to create APIs with different versions to support this or you can use dynamic endpoints as your endpoint of the API.

Comment: "I want to have the APIs deployed in several environments but using only one WSO2 APIM" for this you need to create a distributed setup with multiple gateways.